# View and ViewLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to have many cards(Rect class + ShapeDrawable for adding a color ) on the screen and would like to move each card on the screen when the user touches it.There could be many of them on the screen and each one might be stacked.I mean one below the other with cases like partially overlapping , fully hidden etc..

So is there a way by which i can attach each card(Rect Class+ShapeDrawable) with its corresponding touch event so that I need not manually iterate over all the list of cards and see which one the user has touched.

Should i extend view and do it? Are there any better ways of managing it?

Thanks